# What's the bit that slides into the hot shoe called?

Tags: flash, terminology, hotshoe-flash, accessories, hotshoe

If the metal "U"-bracket on top of an SLR (and similar) camera is called a (hot/cold) shoe, what is the name of it's counterpart (the bit at the base of the flash/accessory)?

I just referred to it as a (hot) foot.. but that just sounds wrong.

[image: hot foot]

Comment: It appears to be consistently referred to as a "mounting foot," if you google "speedlight parts diagram" and check the first few images - but I have no idea of a suitable reference (or creative commons diagram that could be used in an answer).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I've seen that before. Sounds better when you say it like that though.

Comment: I really want it to be the "hot foot".

Comment: Hahaha, according to Wikipedia: "The *hot foot* is a prank where the prankster sets the victim's shoe laces or shoe on fire with a match or lighter."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called the *foot* — the thing that goes into a shoe. You can find this in [ISO 518:2006], the standard which describes the... standard... hot shoe. It's not, however, *defined* there — it's just basically used as if everyone knows what it means. (Which, I guess, we do.)

> The dimensions given in Figures 1 and 2 are basic for the solid shoe. When an accessory shoe is equipped with springs or other devices for holding the accessory foot tightly or maintaining good electrical contact, the dimensions of the shoe can be changed within the range in which their interchangeability and functions will not be affected.

(Emphasis added.) We can see here that they use "accessory foot"; things like "flash foot" also make sense when the accessory is in fact a flash. I've also seen the term "ISO foot" — a flash or accessory foot which matches this standard.

Comment: "hot shoe to locking foot" https://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?A=details&O=&Q=&ap=y&c3api=1876%2C%7Bcreative%7D%2C%7Bkeyword%7D&gclid=Cj0KCQjw_o7NBRDgARIsAKvAgt1jzUpZW1M0BAXrlQiDZEAouv1d09I9p1y9f0l4yvSDdd_REF9VCEgaAkzOEALw_wcB&is=REG&m=Y&sku=767442

Comment: Extra credit for the ISO reference number.